# Backing-up Postgresql data when only root login is available (Ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql, backup, ubuntu, root

I have a Ubuntu-based workstation with several boot issues that prevent any user login - only logging in as "root" works. Before formatting the Ubuntu partition to perform a clean installation, I wanted to backup the users' Postgresql database data.

However, since it is not possible to start PG clusters as root, I cannot start databases as roots or log-in as PG user in root prompt.

Question: is there a way I could backup PG database data in Ubuntu if only root login is available?

Note that, fortunately or not, database data location was set to be a different partition from the OS installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“root” is the all-powerful administrative user. If you are root, you can become user `postgres` with

```bash
su - postgres
```

Then you can start PostgreSQL as usual.

If you are on Ubuntu Linux, you may have a systemd service set up that you can use to start PostgreSQL as root user:

```bash
systemctl start postgres
```

If that doesn't do the trick, resort to the first method.

Comment: Great & simple solution. Thanks!